# I want maintain history of a table in another table in MYSQL .MYSQL WORKBENCH

Tags: mysql, history

Table employee contain columns id, name, age, salary, created(Timestamp). When the Table is created the records is inserted in the employee table as well as in the employee history table which contains the same columns as employee table. History maintain in MYSQL.

Comment: write a insert/update/Delete  trigger where you catch changes and save them

Comment: Yeh its easy way. I want to do it with stored procedures means calling a procedure inside procedure.

Comment: you can call a stored procedure from a trigger, but as you can use almost all the procidure can like loops cursors and so on, it is not really necessary, but do as you see fit